# curl jq get value from field name

Tags: shell-script, curl, jq

```
created=$(curl  -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data "$(payload)"  https://myurl/resource)
```

The above return a json object

```
{
  "revision": {
    "clientId": "",
    "version": 1,
    "lastModifier": "admin"
  },
  "id": "idvalue",
  "uri": "https://myurl/idvalue",
  "position": {
    "x": 100,
    "y": 200
  }
}
```

I am using the below code to get id from above object

```
idvar=$(echo $created | jq ' .id' )
```

but the above gives me the below error

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from `curl` will contain HTTP headers because you request these with `-i` (`--include`).  This means that the contents of your `created` variable will contain HTTP headers, then some JSON.

The `jq` tool can not parse HTTP headers, so it complains.  A standard HTTP response header starts with something like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. The location "line 1, column 9" happens to be where this string has its first space character, where the JSON parser gives up and reports an error.

Removing the `-i` option from the `curl` invocation should make your code work, although if you just need the value of the `id` key, there is really no need to store the output of `curl` in an intermediate variable:

```bash
curl -X POST \
    --header 'Content-Type:application/json' \
    --data "$json_document" \
    'https://myurl/resource' | jq -r .id
```

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the space from your query string it works:

```
$ idvar=$(echo $created | jq '.id' )
$ echo $idvar
"idvalue"
$
```

I would consider using jp from JMESpath (https://github.com/jmespath/jp) as it has a better precisely defined  language syntax.

```
$ echo $created | jp "id"
"idvalue"
$
```

Comment: The `jq` utility would have no issue using the expression with any amount of added space between terms.